# Can I have UIView shown at bottom of the screen and keyboard presented on top of it when needed?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to have either custom  `UIView` or `UIToolbar` or `inputAccessoryView` always visible at the bottom of the screen and not being covered by keyboard when one is presented.

Also keyboard should be visible, meaning it should be presented on top of that view and dismissed accordingly.

It would be nice to have that view as part of the UIViewController, but if it can be part of keyboard it is also acceptable as I have an idea how to achieve the visual impression of it being a part of UIViewController and always visible.

I've run into answers explaining how to add custom toolbar docked at the bottom and shown on top of keyboard once presented.

I've also run into posts explaining how to create a custom keyboard.

There are also some stating keyboard can't be positioned otherwise than docked at the bottom.

I understand if Apple is forcing consistency, but having that view always visible would keep consistency across my app. Therefore, if the final answer is it's not possible, I would appreciate firm explanation or link to apple's mention of this issue, cause I wasn't able to find one so far.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: if on top of it is acceptable, just change the constraints or place of origin of the toolbar to be on top of the keyboard when the keyboard is visible?

Comment: Unfortunately not, as I mentioned in question I'm aware of such solution but it doesn't satisfy my needs. I would really like to have it at bottom if it is possible in any way (including writing my own keyboard extension from scratch). Thanks anyway!

Comment: @doommons - It's unlikely you'll find a way to reposition the keyboard. If the other options you've looked at are not satisfactory, you'll probably need to create your own custom keyboard - which you could then display in any manner you wish.

Comment: You can't do that. but if you want to do something like that you have to implement with your own keyboard extension with your custom UI

Comment: Hi.. If you have any image to display than that would be helpful..